# Why dative verb in some cases are used as akkusative?

Tags: dative

- *Schmecken* is dative verb.
- *Drohen* is dative verb.

But why?

- Ich schmecke den Fish.
- Es droht die Ernte.

Here it is akkusative?

Comment: I’m not sure you fully understand what *dative verb* means and I’m not sure you’re applying that definition correctly to *etw. schmecken* or *jdm etw. (an)drohen.*

Comment: These example sentences are a bit odd. Where did you find them?

Comment: »Es droht die Ernte« = "The harvest threatens" - This doesn't make much sense to me. Btw: In this sentence there is no accusative case, just two times nominative case.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I would like to liken it to ‘Es droht Arbeit’ ;-). But I will also note that the *es* doesn’t have to be considered nominative—or anything else for that matter. It may be a philosophical question if the expletive has a case at all.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Man könnte auch "Es droht ein Gewitter" sagen.

Comment: "Es droht eine _schlechte_ Ernte." is often used as it is a thread (while the harvest itself usually isn't to a farmer)

Comment: @Jan: Da das Expletivum das Subjekt ist, kann es in keinem anderen Fall als dem Nominativ stehen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Nein. Wäre das Expletiv ein Subjekt, müsste sich das Verb in Person und Numerus danach richten. Außerdem kann es nur ein Subjekt in einem Satz geben. Beispiel: »Es werden Dinge erzählt.« Subjekt ist *Dinge*, das Verb steht im Plural und das Expletiv im sonst leeren Vorfeld.

Comment: @Marzipanherz: did you mean *threat* (Drohung)? A *thread* (Faden) seems inappropriate.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis :) yes, you're right

Answer (score 10):

As for *drohen*: You don't specify an object in your example, that's why there's nothing in Dative case here. Dative verb means, that the **object** is in dative case.

A full example would be:

> Die Ernte droht (den Bauern <- object in Dative Plural case)

*Es droht die Ernte* is the same thing as *Die Ernte droht*, just a different word order. That's why you need to additional "Es" in the beginning of the sentence.

As for *schmecken*: There are two different constructions here. One is "Etwas (Nominative) schmeckt jemandem (Dative)". Again, the object is in Dative case.

> Das Essen schmeckt mir
>   Das Eis schmeckt dem Kind

Then, there's also the construction "etwas schmecken" (to taste something), where the object is actually in Accusative case.

> Ich schmecke einen Hauch von Zimt
>   Ich schmecke nichts, weil ich erkältet bin

So in the end you're just mixing up different constructions ;-) This can lead to funny misunderstandings. For example, the following sentences do not mean the same thing:

> Ich schmecke dem Löwen (Dat. Sing) - the lion eats you and likes the taste
>   Ich schmecke den Löwen (Dat. Plur) - the pack of lions eats you and they like the taste
>   Ich schmecke den Löwen (Akk. Sing) - you're tasting a lion (how?)

Comment: You gotta lick it.

Comment: @tofro First I had written "you're licking a lion", but I quickly changed it... :'-D

Answer (score 1):

Thorsten's answer is good, but I want to show you a simple way how to tell when a verb needs a dative object and when not. It matches a lot of those "dative verbs", so you can concentrate on learning the few exceptions.

- Most times, the dative object is the **receiver** of the result of an action.

If the action involves a thing which is passed, that thing is the accusative object.

> Ich gebe **dir** den Koffer.

Here, *dir* is the receiver of the passed accusative object *den Koffer*.

But there are a lot of verbs which include the thing passed implicitly. *Drohen* is such a verb.

> Er ist zu schnell gefahren. **Ihm** droht nun ein Bußgeld.

It's *die Drohung* of the fine which is passed to *him*.

The verb *schmecken* is a bit more complicated, because it's actually two verbs:

> Ich schmecke das Bier. Ich trinke das Bier.

Here, I perform the action of *schmecken* on the beer. So the beer is an accusative object. Same as with *trinken*.

> Das Bier schmeckt **mir**.

Here, the beer performs an action on me! It passes the *Geschmack* included in the action *schmecken*.

It's not a 100% rule, but at least 80% and should help you identify those "dative verbs" and their use.